# Export/Import - Users and Groups and Permissions SP 2007

Tags: permissions, groups

Recently i was asked to migrate an existing 2007 site to a new 2007 site. This involved creating a different structure in the new site as well as bringing across some of the data (lists) from the old site. I used stsadm extension methods (GL) to automate the export and import of the lists, and also made many changes to the navigation and site settings, list settings, webparts, workflows etc...

I have now learnt that the original backup of the existing site did not include the user security (-includeusersecurity) - i did not personally do it.

Now what i find is that i have all the users from the original site, but only the default groups exist, and none of the users are part of those groups (well, some are but not many) - so, now users on the site are having all sorts of problems that 'appear' to be related to permissions - views not appearing, password boxes popping up, able to access lists they shouldnt be able to, or vice versa, etc...

Now, i'm aware that i could just re-export the original site, but then i would have to re-do all my changes, and given that there are in excess of 30 sub-sites, this is probably over a weeks worth of work to get right not to mention the potential for introducing more errors/mistakes.

Is there a way to export the users and groups and associated permissions from one site and then import them into another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at AvePoint and Quest tools, either their migration or administration products have permission mapping components.

AvePoint is currently giving away 100GB with their migration tool.  This tool can migrate security.

http://www.avepoint.com/sharepoint-migration-promotion/

The alternative is to custom write a module that pulls all the site/list permissions for a user from that site and applies it to your new site.

Links that may help for custom solution:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms469194.aspx

http://sanketinfo.wordpress.com/2009/05/06/how-to-get-roles-and-permission-for-sharepoint-siteweb/

http://digsharepoint.blogspot.com/2011/03/get-item-level-permissions-using-client.html

Comment: thanks for the detailed response. I did manage at the time to muddle through it (although rather painfully). I'm sure i would have found your suggestions useful.

Comment: Figured I might throw an answer up here in case someone else has the same issue.  I am dealing with a variation of it now, and utilizing the AvePoint tools.